# Set OpenID Connect CallbackPath to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application that is hosted in AWS behind an https load balancer. To the outside world it is an https site, but to AWS internally it runs on http behind the balancer.

Because of this the OpenID Connect middleware is redirecting to the HTTP path instead of HTTPS.

Is there anyway to force OpenId Connect to use https pathing?

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    var oauthConfig = Configuration.GetSection("OAuthConfiguration").Get<OAuthConfiguration>();

    options.Authority = oauthConfig.Authority;
    options.ClientId = oauthConfig.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = oauthConfig.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
```

When the authorization request is made this generates this redirect uri

`"RedirectUri": "http://demo.mysite.com/signin-oidc"`

I cannot hardcore a path into the `CallbackPath` because my application runs multitenancy and the URL is different depending upon routing.

Comment: How has this only got 7 up votes? Most .NET Core HTTP websites behind a load balancer must have this issue.

Answer (score 16):

You can force the provider to rewrite your callback url in https like this

```
option.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    var builder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                    builder.Scheme = "https";
                    builder.Port = -1;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URI should be an HTTPS value:

- Login response returned to https://web.mycompany.com/myapp?code=a0wfd78
- Load balancer routes the response to http://server1/myapp?code=a0wfd78

In terms of multitenancy I would try to avoid interfering with the Open Id Connect login process and instead use the same callback path for all users. That is the standard behaviour, and using things like wildcards in redirect URIs can create security vulnerabilities.

Not sure I fully understand understand your requirements related to multitenancy, so if this doesn't work for you, please post some further details on how you want it to work.

.Net Core has events you can override, such as this one, if the redirect URI needs to be calculated at runtime:

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
{
    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = <load balanced value>;
    await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately my client is all about white labeling and that extends to their picky URLs. How that works is my code just listens to localhost:80 in AWS and a route 53 entry is pointed to a loadbalancer so they can pick their own URL. I was able to convince my devops to update the AWS task to a HTTPS protocol which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The answer here is to insert middleware that pretends all requests came in as HTTPS. Works for me.

[ASP.NET 5 OAuth redirect URI not using HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276849/asp-net-5-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)

---

**Warning**

The following doesn't work. When deployed it causes a "Correlation failed" error, presumably because the URL was tampered with.

---

This is the complete fix for my website. Note that I'm loading my options from config.

```
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    this.Configuration.Bind("OAuth2:Providers:Google", options);

    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub", "string");

    options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = MakeHttps;
})
```

Importantly, this event actually performs the redirect, else you'll get a 200 OK and a blank page.

```
private Task MakeHttps(RedirectContext<OAuthOptions> arg)
{
    // When behind a load balancer the redirect URL, which is configured as CallbackPath in the appsettings.json
    // is created as HTTP because the HTTPS request is terminated at the NLB and is forwarded in clear text.

    // The policy of most OAuth IDPs is to disallow clear HTTP redirect URLs.

    if (!arg.RedirectUri.Contains("redirect_uri=https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        arg.RedirectUri = arg.RedirectUri.Replace("redirect_uri=http","redirect_uri=https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    arg.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(arg.RedirectUri);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```